# MbUnit and Resharper integration not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, mbunit, gallio

I set up a new machine this week. It is running Windows 7, 64 bit.
I installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional, then [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) 5.0, rapidly followed by Resharper 5.1  when it came out soon after.
Since I have a project with tests in MbUnit, I have installed [MbUnit/Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/), using the 3.1.397 version x64 msi installer from [here](http://www.gallio.org/Downloads.aspx).

I was expecting to see the green gutter icons that Reshaper puts next to my tests, but I do not. I tried removing Gallio and installing the 32 bit version. No change. I re-installed both Resharper as Gallio as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449853/my-resharper-gutter-icons-for-unit-tests-arent-showing), but this produced no change. In this procedure, `%APPDATA%` is set to `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming`, so I deleted `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains`. I have also tried unstalling both Reshaper and gallio, deleting all Resharper and Gallio data from `AppData\Roaming`, `AppData\Local`, and `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and then installing again from a cmd running as admin, but again, no change.

Resharper has no plugins listed in the Plugins dialog, and in the `Resharper|Options|Unit testing` item the "unit testing providers" listed are MSTest and nUnit.

Visual studio has two other Add-ins listed: ".Net Reflector" and "Visual Git".

What do I have to do to get MBUnit working in Resharper?

Which of these two tools provides the integration? Should I install Resharper or Gallio first?

Where do the integration files or settings go? It has been suggested that I should have a "resharper plugins directory" in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v5.1\Plugins` or similar but this is not present at all.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634665/gallio-test-runner-plugin-to-visual-studio-2008-and-2010-for-mbunit-tests

Answer (score 3):

[**R# 5.1 RTW** is supported by **Gallio/MbUnit**](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-user/browse_thread/thread/560b0fb3d1bea39e) starting from v3.2.512. You can download the latest binaries of the Gallio bundle in the [daily builds repository](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/). v3.2 is not officially released yet but it is very stable already.

UPDATE 1: [R#5.1 officially supported](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2010/07/gallio-v32-resharper-51.html).
UPDATE 2: [Gallio v3.2 RC](http://gallio.org/Downloads.aspx) with R# 5.0 and 5.1 support.

Comment: When will it be released? Prefer to wait for releases for obvious reasons.

Comment: Gallio v3.2 is going to pass in RC in a couple of days. The final version should then come quickly.

Comment: I have the same problem, even though I run Gallio 3.3.1 (the latest official release at the moment).